# Enterprise Edition theme fallback

Tags: magento-enterprise, theme-fallback

The theme fallback on CE is

- custom-package/custom-theme
- custom-package/default
- base/default

However in the Enterprise Edition, there is an added enterprise/default package and theme. So does the fallback become

- custom-package/custom-theme
- custom-package/default
- enterprise/default
- base/default

??

According to this link

https://www.sonassi.com/blog/magento-kb/magento-enterprise-theme-fallback

it doesn't seem like it was the case at the time of writing, but they mentioned they submitted it to the Magento dev team. I'm wondering if this has been addressed, and if so in which EE version?

In versions where this isn't the case (or if it isn't the case at all), what are we supposed to do when we have custom package and theme? Copy everything over from enterprise/default to our custom-package/custom-theme??

Comment: This is not the case at all indeed. Sonassi's post is correct, EE does not fallback to the enterprise/default, so you have to copy its contents into your custom-package/default.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Confident enough in that to make it an answer?